# cannot parse object when trying to reset git HEAD to last commit

Tags: python, git, subprocess, popen

I have a a subprocess  command that runs on the server that reset git head to the last commit. like this

```
args = [
    "git",
    "reset",
    "--hard",
    str(self.commit_id),
]

process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=self.project_directory)
stdout = process.communicate()[0]

if process.returncode != 0:
    error_text = "Error attempting to reset to '{}'\n".format(self.commit_id)
    error_text += "Command: {}\n".format(" ".join(args))
    error_text += "Output: \n"
    error_text += stdout
```

but this throws error:

```
SystemError: Error attempting to reset to '9eada053b68fbe7209096b214294959f90a87b67'
Command: git reset --hard 9eada053b68fbe7209096b214232329f90a87b67
Output:
fatal: Could not parse object '9eada053b68fbe7209096b214232329f90a87b67'.
```

9eada053b68fbe7209096b214232329f90a87b67 is the last commit on the branch.

Comment: You could format with `{!r}` rather than just `{}` to check for otherwise-invisible characters.

Comment: how can there be invisible characters in a commit id, but do you mean `Error attempting to reset to '{!r}'\n".format(self.commit_id)` ?

Comment: I'm suspicious that you might have some sort of non-printable character in the hash ID, yes. That would show it. It may be something else entirely, this is just one guess / possibility.

Comment: noting showed up and I recon that as I have myself created different commit and all seem to through the same error